# Conveying "learn/know enough (sth) to be dangerous"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

This is something that it has puzzled me for some time. I'm feeling that a word-by-word translation would not work in French. How can one convey colloquially in French:

> Learn (or know) Enough to Be Dangerous

as in

> The name “Learn Enough” refers to the philosophy is that you don’t
> have learn everything about most subjects—you just have to learn
> enough to be dangerous.
>
> In this context, “dangerous” is meant to have a positive meaning,
> indicating that you are able to get things done.

taking from:

[https://www.learnenough.com/our-philosophy#:~:text=Our%20Philosophy-,Learn%20Enough%20to%20Be%20Dangerous,able%20to%20get%20things%20done](https://www.learnenough.com/our-philosophy#:%7E:text=Our%20Philosophy-,Learn%20Enough%20to%20Be%20Dangerous,able%20to%20get%20things%20done)

See also a relevant question here:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158755/is-there-a-way-to-express-knowing-just-enough-to-be-dangerous-succintly

Here is an application in an academic context:

http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/mathematica-cheat-sheet.pdf

Comment: "En apprendre juste assez pour être dangereux" seems to fit just fine... but to me conveys the idea of not knowing enough still to be efficient. Like knowing a bit of chemistry can be enough to be dangerous and you need more to be safe...

Comment: Yes I think the word is ironic, it's what we could call "minimum vital" knowledge.

Comment: le bagage minimal? les bases du métier? guide de survie?